# select data.table R rows based on row number and condition

Tags: r, data.table

In data.table, we can select rows based on row number or condition:

```
> x <- data.table(letters[1:4], 1:4)
> x
   V1 V2
1:  a  1
2:  b  2
3:  c  3
4:  d  4
> x[2]
   V1 V2
1:  b  2
> x[V1 == "d"]
   V1 V2
1:  d  4
```

However I can't select with both row number and condition:

```
> x[!2 & V2 > 1]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: V1,V2
```

This is probably because the `!2` is not interpreted as row number in this format. I knew I can chain the two conditions:

```
> x[!2][V2 > 1]
   V1 V2
1:  c  3
2:  d  4
```

However I wanted to assign new column values for this subset

```
x[!2][V2 > 1, V3 := "more"]
```

Now it only created column for the intermediate chained data.table. I can save the intermediate table then merge back to the original table, but that will be cumbersome.

Actually I often feel `data.table` need a proper row number. `.I` is a dynamic number depend on group, but I wanted a unique id that can identify every row, this unique id can be very useful in merge/join (often the data don't have a unique id). If `.i` is the row number, I can use

```
x[(.i != 2) & (V2 >1), V3 := "more"]
```

I can simulate this by creating a row number column explicitly first.

Another method is to make the modifications on subset data.table apply back the original table. Suppose we have x as original table, x[!2] as a subset, then if modifications on `x[!2]` actually modify x, my question will be solved too. Of course this kind of subset need to be created in different way, for example `x[!2, refOriginal = TRUE]`.

Comment: Found a discussion about real row number [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1494), many shared similar opinions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are my two attempts toward the solution: The first one uses the summarize syntax of `data.table` to calculate a logical vector using row number `.I` and condition at position `i` for subsetting and updating columns; the second one uses `which` and `setdiff` to remove certain row numbers from the condition, if on the other hand you need an `and` operation of row number and condition, `setdiff` can be replaced with `union`:

```
x[x[, .I != 2 & V2 > 2], V3 := "more"]
x
#    V1 V2   V3
# 1:  a  1   NA
# 2:  b  2   NA
# 3:  c  3 more
# 4:  d  4 more


x[setdiff(which(V2 > 2), c(2)), V3 := "more"]
x
#    V1 V2   V3
# 1:  a  1   NA
# 2:  b  2   NA
# 3:  c  3 more
# 4:  d  4 more
```

Comment: Thanks for tip on first one. I limited myself on using condition in `i`, while you used the conditions in `j` to create logical vector then work as `i`. It's a clever idea, and maybe the only workaround to use `.I` as row number.  That being said, I'm wondering if this usage is optimized in `data.table`.

Comment: I did a microbenchmark, basically first method is same in performance with the chaining syntax, and normal selective column assignment(without the row number condition) use half time. I think the performance is acceptable.

Comment: This particular question has been solved with cleaver usage of `.I`, but I still think `data.table` need a row number. There are times when all I need can be solved with a for loop and simple logic with row number, but it could be very hard with current syntax, or need to be really creative. I think a row number should not bring the same overhead of row.names in data frame.